# Is there a safe C++ wrapper for a non owning pointer to a single object?

Tags: c++, pointers

We have std::smart pointers for expressing ownership. It seems a good idea to me that we should have a way of explicitly expressing non-ownership. Std::span gives this to us for a raw pointer to an array. But what about a raw pointer to a single object? A wrapper type should ban pointer arithmetic and delete, and probably also ban null pointers, since we have std::optional to express the possibility of a null pointer.
If we had a wrapper for a non owning pointer to single object, we could ban raw pointers altogether.
Is there such a thing in the std?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr but it was not (yet) accepted because there are divergent opinions about it.

Comment: see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1408r0.pdf for an example of proposal to remove it

Comment: I don't think non-owning smart-pointer can fix the 2 of the most problematic use-cases: _"use after free"_ or _"double delete"_.  So what would be the benefits of such a smart-pointer ? If the proposed smart-pointer is non-owning, this implies that some other object is the owner and could delete the pointed to object.  `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` will currently do the job.

Comment: Isn't this just a reference? Or a maybe a `reference_wrapper` if you want it in an `optional`?

Comment: Why not to use weak_pointer?

Comment: A weak pointer needs to be associated with a shared pointer, but we might want a pointer to a unique owned object or a stack based object. The point of such a wrapper is to express explicitly that this is a non owning pointer, rather than just hoping that smart pointers have been used for all owned resources and that raw pointers are therefore non owning. This is the current position in the guidelines. But explicitness rather than implicitness is preferred.